# Dynamically Creating and Naming Grid Elements

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, user-interface

I have been trying to create a Gantt chart style timetable for a project I am working on. I am currently having trouble with the UI of said chart.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPLyZ.jpg]

As you can see from my highly advanced mockup, events will be represented by a box (a grid) stretching from start to end time.

The problem I am having is creating these grids an infinite number of times from my code.
I would like, ideally, for each grid to have it's own unique but dynamically generated name. For example, the "Breakfast" event's grid would be called grid1, the Internationals Breakfast would be called grid2, the Keys Workshop grid3, as so on for as many grids as my program creates, potentially to infinity.

So, I know how to create grids with

```
 Grid aGrid = new Grid();
```

But how would I go about giving each grid a different name?
I hope I've been vaguely coherent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean a different variable name?

if you have a list of grids, you should be storing them in some type of collection, like a `List<Grid>` or `ObservableCollection<Grid>`, then you dont need to worry about naming them.

if thats not what you meant, and you want a unique Element Name for each Grid, then you could just have a grid counter that increments for each grid you create, and use that as the grid name

```
Grid aGrid = new Grid();
aGrid.Name = "Grid" + gridCounter++;
```

Comment: Upon first look, that second one seems to be what I want! I'll give it a go!